# How to use the PHP bitwise AND operator with Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I am trying to do what PHP does with the `&` `AND` operator but in javascript. An example would be the following:

```php
// PHP
$a = '100110100011111000100110';
$b = '111111111111111111111110';

echo $a & $b //100110100011111000100110
```

Well, it is the result that I must achieve in javascript ... trying it from the beginning would be ..

```js
// JS
const a = 100110100011111000100110;
const b = 111111111111111111111110;

console.log(a & b) //536870912
```

Honestly, I know very little about binary, I have tried some functions using bitwise XOR and reviewed the topic right here in StackOverflow but the truth is confused.

Comment: Both `100110100011111000100110` and `111111111111111111111110` are larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in JavaScript. You likely shouldn't be representing them as numbers. Moreover, bitwise operations will further truncate the numbers to a 32-bit integer.

Comment: You first have to convert the binary representations into actual numbers (-> `parseInt()`). Do the "math", and if you need the result also in its "binary" form use `.toString()` (-> `Number.prototype.toString()`) if you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to the comments of those who responded, and looking and entering the topic, I reviewed the documentation of both languages and then what I did was divide the strings, and do the `and - &` to each pair of their position and the result it was similar to php.

here as I did.

```js
const a = '100110100011111000100110';
const b = '111111111111111111111110';

function andBin (one, two) {
  const _a = one.split('')
  const _b = two.split('')
  let result = ''

  _a.map((e, i) => {
    result += Number(e) & Number(_b[i])
  })

  return result

}

andBin(a, b) // 100110100011111000100110
```

ready. resolved, thank you all very much.

Comment: That's not how [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is meant to be used. This should be a `for` loop or [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)